# Import Error in Python Textbook Sample Program

Tags: python, import

I am following a Python textbook and it contains an error in a sample program below:

```
# Random Access
# Demonstrates string indexing

import random

word = "index"
print "The word is:", word, "\n"

high = len(word)
low = -len(word)
for i in range(10):
    position = random.randrange(low, high)
    print "word[", position, "]\t", word[position]

raw_input("\n\nPress enter to exit.")
```

Python complains with the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\random.py", line 3, in <module>
import random   

File "C:\Python27\random.py", line 11, in <module>
    position = random.randrange(low, high) AttributeError: 'module' object has 
    no attribute 'randrange'
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I am new to programming and python.
I have used the "import random" code before and it worked fine.

Comment: Don't name your file "random.py". Also, don't use the Python dir as your workspace

Comment: @JBernardo thank you, it works now. The textbook did not warn of this!

Comment: Please don't add the word 'SOLVED' to your question title; mark the solution as accepted instead. For a self-answer that takes a little longer, but your question may be useful to others in the future too, solved or not, a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used the Python folder as my working directory and named the script "random.py".